# how to get multiple types of file using pathsForResourcesOfType

Tags: iphone

I need to access all jpg,png,bmp in my Resources folder, but 
doing the following only gives me jpg...
is it algorithmically wrong?
or is there a shorter, simpler syntax that makes me access all three at once?
Please help me out..

```
NSMutableArray *paths = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:nil] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *paths2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *paths3 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bmp" inDirectory:nil] mutableCopy];

for(NSString *filename in paths)
{
    filename = [filename lastPathComponent];
    NSLog(@" filename is %@", filename);
    [filenames addObject:filename];
    NSLog(@" filenames array length is now %d", [filenames count]);
}
```

and so on for paths2 and paths3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `nil` for the extension to retrieve all bundle resources. Then, in the `for` loop, check for `[filename pathExtension]`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with @Ole Begemann's solution is that you will be reiterating through a lot of files that aren't images. I think @CosmicRabbitMediaInc was on the right track with the mutable array, but didn't follow through. So:

```
NSMutableArray *paths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:nil]];
[paths addObjectsFromArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil]];
[paths addObjectsFromArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bmp" inDirectory:nil]];

for(NSString *filename in paths)
{
    filename = [filename lastPathComponent];
    NSLog(@" filename is %@", filename);
    [filenames addObject:filename];
    NSLog(@" filenames array length is now %d", [filenames count]);
}
```